# How to avoid generation of a joined table while using @manytomany mapping

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have a mapping in my feedback entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="feedback")
public class Feedback {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    //getters and setters
}
```

It is creating a joined table feedback_users in my database..

```
>desc feedback_users;

>feedback_id    bigint(20)  NO  PRI
 users_id       bigint(20)  NO  PRI
```

How to avoid the generation of the mapped table feedback_users but still I the mapping should be there ..

Comment: you should have google 1st   any way try this - https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/

Comment: Why did you deleted all the content of your question ?...

Comment: set FetchType Lazy

Comment: still feedback_users table is there bro. .. I dont want to generate feedback_users table .. I set FetchType Lazy and tried :-(